# AS3 microphone recording/saving works, in-flash PCM playback double speed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, wav, audio-recording, audio-player

I have a working mic recording script in AS3 which I have been able to successfully use to save .wav files to a server through AMF. These files playback fine in any audio player with no weird effects.

For reference, here is what I am doing to capture the mic's ByteArray: (within a class called AudioRecorder)

```
public function startRecording():void {
_rawData = new ByteArray();
_microphone
 .addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA,_samplesCaptured, false, 0, true);
}

private function _samplesCaptured(e:SampleDataEvent):void {
  _rawData.writeBytes(e.data);
}
```

This works with no problems. After the recording is complete I can take the _rawData variable and run it through a WavWriter class, etc.

However, if I run this same ByteArray as a sound using the following code which I adapted from the adobe cookbook: (within a class called WavPlayer)

```
public function playSound(data:ByteArray):void {
  _wavData = data;
  _wavData.position = 0;
  _sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, _playSoundHandler);
  _channel = _sound.play();
  _channel
    .addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, _onPlaybackComplete, false, 0, true);
}

private function _playSoundHandler(e:SampleDataEvent):void {
  if(_wavData.bytesAvailable <= 0) return;
  for(var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
    var sample:Number = 0;
    if(_wavData.bytesAvailable > 0) sample = _wavData.readFloat();
    e.data.writeFloat(sample);
  }
}
```

The audio file plays at double speed! I checked recording bitrates and such and am pretty sure those are all correct, and I tried changing the buffer size and whatever other numbers I could think of. Could it be a mono vs stereo thing?

Hope I was clear enough here, thanks!

Comment: You should stick to the "actionscript-3" tag for AS3 questions. That's what's commonly used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the ByteArray has to contain data for both channels (left and right), one value immediately after the other. Thus, *if your recording is mono*, your code should be this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
    var sample:Number = 0;
    if(_wavData.bytesAvailable > 0) sample = _wavData.readFloat();
        e.data.writeFloat(sample);
        e.data.writeFloat(sample);
}
```

If it is stereo, you will need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: So it was a stereo/mono thing! I didn't think to writeFloat twice, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've tested it.
You need to make sure the Microphone's rate is at 44kHz:
_microphone.rate = 44;
This should sound right.

I used:

```
    private function playSound(data:ByteArray):void
    {
        rawData = data;
        rawData.position = 0;
        var sound:Sound = new Sound();
        sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playSoundHandler);
        var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();
        channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function playSoundHandler(e:SampleDataEvent):void
    {
        if(rawData.bytesAvailable <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        for(var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
        {
            var sample:Number = 0;
            if(rawData.bytesAvailable > 0)
            {
                sample = rawData.readFloat();
            }
            e.data.writeFloat(sample);
            e.data.writeFloat(sample);
        }
    }
```