# flash record video from webcam and send to youtube

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, youtube

I need to record video from webcam in Flash and send it to Youtube using Api.
I cant use server and all process must be in client side.
It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

i answered a similar question (but for recording audio) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704852/how-do-i-embed-a-flash-audio-recorder-in-my-site/6707803#6707803)

So yes it is possible to record audio client side, so i don't think it would be all to difficult to figure out how to record the video to, you just need to find the right libraries.

Then once your client has recorded whatever they wanted you can use actionscript's URLRequest to post to youtube (from the client again).

If anything i hope this helps put you in the right direction. Cheers!