# How to record audio as wav/mp3 in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

I want to record audio from a Swf file , not mic , not from network

just a simple swf file in local filesystem .

I use SwfLoader ,  load into my app , and record by :

```
// tigger by ENTEY_FRAME event
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(bytes, false, 0);
this.sound_bytes.writeBytes(bytes); //sound_bytes is ByteArray too
```

by , how to convert sound_bytes into a wav or mp3 ,or another known format ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Hey read the reply to this post a while back on how to record wav or mp3 files using a microphone
[How do I embed a Flash audio recorder in my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704852/how-do-i-embed-a-flash-audio-recorder-in-my-site/6707803#6707803)

I know you are not recording from a microphone but i think this is the general idea of how to do it...
This is how the guy records to a wave file, look in his source code.

```
 WaveFile.writeBytesToWavFile(myWavFile, recorder.output, 16000, 1, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex 4 API allows you to directly do that.
Check the following link out.

http://titansturf.in/2010/02/08/fetching-data-from-the-microhpone-and-recording-sound/