# Capture Audio Input with flash or html5

Tags: javascript, flash, html, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to capture the microphone and send the recording to my server.. I tried this method [here](http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) but it records only a big WAV and the upload can be slow sometimes.
**Is there a way to capture the voice and compress it on the client side?**
Best method would be to send the recording while recording, but I have no Idea if this is possible. (It works for YouTube Live Webcam recording, it must work for Audio only too..)

Comment: The officially supported way of doing this kind of thing with Flash is to have Adobe Flash Media Server, or the open source alternative Red5 (http://red5.org/) on the server side, and connect the Flash client to it using the NetConnection and NetStream objects in ActionScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check out this post where i replied to a guy with a similar question as you.

[How do I embed a Flash audio recorder in my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704852/how-do-i-embed-a-flash-audio-recorder-in-my-site/6707803#6707803)

i dont know about client side compressing (i have looked into it before and couldnt find anything). But i know you can severely reduce the size of the file by limiting the rate of recording via these numbers here, where if i recall correctly 16 is 16khz recording

```
 recorder = new MicRecorder(wavencoder,null,50,16);
```

also sending to the server is not that hard, just look up how to post data, because the wav file is essentially binary data

Comment: hope this helps, and also please let me know if you find out how to compress an audio file on the client side, and how effective it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compress the file on the clientside using libmp3lame.js: https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js

There is already a gitHub project that uses this library to record audio and save it in MP3 format directly in the browser:

https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js