# CoffeeScript: Record Voice and output text

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor

I am making a package for github's atom.
In that I need to record voice and output it on the window.

How do I record voice and output is as text in coffeeScript?

Comment: Find a voice-to-text library. If you can't find one in JavaScript, find one that you can compile to JS (Emscripten for C/C++, Ruby on Rails for Ruby, etc.). Also, I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: I find this to be a very intriguing queston, even though it lacks some effort. A pity it gets downvoted so fast without any hint of explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Record Voice

This has been asked a lot:

- [Can I use javascript to record voice on a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082689/can-i-use-javascript-to-record-voice-on-a-web-app)
- [Capture Audio Input with flash or html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587882/capture-audio-input-with-flash-or-html5)
- [HTML5 record audio to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)

### 2. Output as text

Now comes the tricky part (not that the previous step is easy): You need **speech recognition**. Here are some js libraries you could use:

- [Pocketsphinx.js](http://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/)
- [annyang!](https://www.talater.com/annyang/)

### Alternative: Web Speech API

If you're up to the task of building your own speech recognition and want to learn new stuff, go ahead. I've done it once with tcl/tk and there was a lot of learning but also fun involved. However, it takes some time to get it right, i.e. get usable results. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, just use the Web Speech API:

- [Web Speech API Specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html)
- [Web Speech API Demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)

Comment: Thanks! Will go through all of that!

Comment: I read through almost all of that and yes it is indeed possible for a web app (Though there might be some bugs while actually doing it). 
I am particularly looking for something for the Github Atom Editor. 
Do you think Pocketsphinx.js can be used from Atom? 
I am relatively knew to JS.

Comment: Github's Atom is based on Node.js and WebKit, using CoffeeScript, HTML and CSS. I would assume that it's possible to fully integrate Pocketsphinx.js. I certainly would like to see a speech to text feature in there!

Comment: @frhd did you find a way to run Pocketsphinx on Atom package?

Comment: @frhd did you try any library to get voice in Atom?

Comment: @MouhamadKawas: I haven't tried. I don't use Atom, actually.